# How do you identify a sparse tensor for output purposes?

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, tensorflow-lite, tensorflow-serving

To get the prediction / output of my pre-trained model; the [model](https://github.com/OMR-Research/tf-end-to-end) predicts a symbol for each frame (column) of the convoluted image and it is necessary to conduct post-processing of the logits (output of the RNN) to emit the actual sequence of predicted symbols. Code for model construction can be found [here](https://github.com/OMR-Research/tf-end-to-end/blob/master/ctc_model.py).

```
logits = graph.get_tensor_by_name("fully_connected/BiasAdd:0")
decoded, _ = tf.nn.ctc_greedy_decoder(logits, seq_len)
prediction = sess.run(decoded,
                      feed_dict={
                          input: image,
                          seq_len: seq_lengths,
                          rnn_keep_prob: 1.0,
                      })
```

`Prediction` is a SparseTensorValue containing every predicted symbol. `Decoded` is a sparse tensor of non-empty tensors. Ultimately, I parse the resulting SparseTensorValue for the strings I need.

I want to use this trained model for inference either through tensorflow serving or tflite, however in order to proceed I would need to indicate the output nodes for the model. Given the nature of sparse tensors, I won't be able to indicate it by name. Is there a way for me to use this model for proper inference?

I've seen many examples of using ctc decoders such as [this](https://github.com/githubharald/SimpleHTR/blob/master/src/Model.py) in a similar way for prediction, however, there were no examples of using these models for inference without closely relying on the tensorflow api, I am unsure how to proceed.

Answer (score 0):

You can save your model to the `tf` *saved_model* format. After that you can use the CLI tool `saved_model_cli` of the package [tensorflow-serving-api](https://pypi.org/project/tensorflow-serving-api/) to inspect all model signatures with: `saved_model_cli show --dir . --all`. Withit you will see all information of the input and output shape(s). The default signature is called `default_serving`.